# Argon2 Hashes Mismatched Between Implementations

Tags: python, go, argon2-ffi

I have some code written in Python using the [Python Argon2 library](https://pypi.org/project/argon2/).

A simple test to encode an email addresses:

```
import argon2
print(argon2.argon2_hash("example@example.com", salt="1558cc06add8a1023cbfa527c5af29fe", t=16, m=8, p=1, buflen=16, argon_type=argon2.Argon2Type.Argon2_i).hex())`
```

Result:

```
f62830118f962095caad9cdbc64e0bc2
```

If I then try the [Argon2 command line untility](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/argon2/argon2.1.en.html) (on Debian Bullseye, up-to-date as of 17th November 2022):

```
echo -n example@example.com | argon2 1558cc06add8a1023cbfa527c5af29fe -t 16 -m 8 -p 1 -l 16 -r
```

(Note the -n option for echo so it doesn't [add a newline at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649970/different-argon2-output-between-reference-implementation-and-go)).

I get:

```
4955d9263eb65cd9071aaea6bc60a93e
```

If I then try in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/argon2"
)

const argon2Iterations uint32 = 16
const argon2Memory uint32 = 8
const argon2Parallelism uint8 = 1
const argon2KeyLength uint32 = 16

func main() {
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(argon2.Key([]byte("example@example.com"), []byte("1558cc06add8a1023cbfa527c5af29fe"), argon2Iterations, argon2Memory, argon2Parallelism, argon2KeyLength)))
}
```

I get:

```
330bb2088c87342a4abe1a987940bbec
```

I then try a couple of web-based hash generators:

https://argon2.online/ - [Screenshot from Argon2 Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSILx.png)

https://antelle.net/argon2-browser/ - [Screenshot from Argon2 In Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtFvd.png)

Both of which return the same as the Go implementation:

```
330bb2088c87342a4abe1a987940bbec
```

My guess is that the "correct" version is the Go version that matches the web-based utilities and that I'm doing something wrong in the way I'm using the Python or command line implementations. However, looking at the code above, I can't figure out what that difference is - I think everything is using the Argon2i algorithm, with the same values for iterations / memory usage and so on, so the resulting hash values should be the same, shouldn't they?